# как переключать базы данных на разных языках в реакте i18next

Tags: reactjs, phpmyadmin, i18n

у меня две одинаковые базы данных только на разных языках. Через i18next переводятся кнопки и названия страниц. А как мне оформить, чтобы к соответвующему языку подключить соотвествующую базу данных ?

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'; //public/locales/translation.json
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'


i18n
    .use(Backend)
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    saveMissing: true,
    debug: true,
    detection: {
        order: ['queryString', 'cookie'],
        cach: ['cookie']
    },
    backend: {
        loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
    },
    interpolation: {
        escapaValue: false
    },
    
});

export default i18n
```